# doing an assignment inside .findAll closure on a collection in Groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a collection in Groovy on which I am using a .findAll() to filter and return me a smaller collection. Say I have an Item table and I want to filter by some property of it, for example:

```
 List<Item> items = Item.list();
 items.findAll { it.price > 0 }
```

Say I added I want to add extra code in that closure like so:

```
 items.findAll {
     int roundedPrice = Math.ceil(it.price);
     roundedPrice > 0;
 }
```

According to the [Groovy docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)), the closure will filter the collection if the closure returns true. However, what I'm curious about is whether or not the assignment for roundedPrice will ever return a "true" on its own.

As the code stands, it works. However, does anyone know whether or not there will issues down the road with an assignment in a closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be - however you could also just do `items.findAll {Math.ceil(it.price) > 0}`

Answer (score 2):

> However, what I'm curious about is whether or not the assignment for
>   roundedPrice will ever return a "true" on its own.

The way you have it written, no.  You could have any number of assignments happening in the closure and those assignments will not direclty affect the return value.  The closure return value will be whatever the last expression in the closure evaluates to.  If you make the assignment the last expression, then it will be treated as “true” as long as the result of the assignment is non-zero.

> As the code stands, it works. However, does anyone know whether or not
>   there will issues down the road with an assignment in a closure?

No, there is no reason to believe that the closure will behave any differently in the future than it does today.

Comment: Just curious.. For the second question, are there any other languages that you know of where this may not be the case?

Comment: "are there any other languages that you know of where this may not be the case" - I don't know what you are asking.  Where what might be the case?

Comment: Ugh.  That last comment of mine is a response to comment that was deleted as soon as I responded to it.

Comment: I apologize. I was reading up more about closures in general and found your answer to be correct so I deleted that last comment. Wasn't the smartest question to ask.

Comment: "...so I deleted that last comment. Wasn't the smartest question to ask." - This is the sort of thing that prompted https://twitter.com/jeffscottbrown/status/456162262286213120. Deleting pieces of a conversation often breaks the conversation.

Comment: I'll remember next time to not to delete it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You've indicated that the items are being loaded from the database. A more efficient way to achieve the same result is

```
Item.findAllByPriceGreaterThan(0)
```

It's inefficient to return all items from the database then filter them in memory, when you do the filtering in the query instead.

Comment: I understand that is inefficient to list all of the objects in the database. I was more concerned about the assignment returning true before the condition is evaluated since it would filter the items incorrectly.

Comment: The assignment will definitely not cause the closure to return true the way you have it written.  The expression `roundedPrice > 0` defines the return value.